# how to set connection timeout in pro/c client side?

Tags: c, linux, oracle, timeout, oracle-pro-c

I am writing a c program under linux to connect to oracle DB and execute a stored procedure using oracle pro/c.
My problem is that I want to make a time out for calling this procedure after which I get control back with let's say a TIME_OUT error (preferably this error would be returned from the pro/c), so how can it be done either programatically or with precombiler option??

my .pc file would contain something like

```
bool connectToDb() {
/*variables declaration and assigning*/
EXEC SQL CONNECT :local_username IDENTIFIED BY :local_password USING :local_connectionString; // to connect to DB
/*error handling*/
}
```

and I call a test procedure that sleeps for say 30 sec. and I would like to make timeout for it lets say 5 sec after those 5 sec I want an error (ORA error) to return indicating timeout

```
bool callProcedure() {
/*variables declaration and assigning*/
EXEC SQL CALL  SLEEP_TEST(); //this line that I don't want to be blocked
/*errors handling*/
}
```

Note: I handle all errors using

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO SQLError;
/*my sql logic*/
goto EndOf_function;
SQLError:
/*Error handling portion that I want to catch the timeout*/
EndOf_function:;
```

any suggestions??

Comment: Did you find the soln?

Comment: Actually I found an answer
you can't set a transaction timeout in oracle pro*c as it uses the instant client that doesn't support transaction timeout
So, no I am looking for alternatives like OCI but still trying to figure out how to use it :)

Comment: How ever, you can set connection timeout in case of trying to "connect" to DB just only in connecting phase by using TNS entry and setting the 
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10) (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)
actually I yet don't know which one  of the previous 2 parameters (CONNECT_TIMEOUT and TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) is the one we need but however I use both till I know which one to use. If those parameters not used then the default timeout as mentioned in Oracle document will be 60 seconds.